# XML Serialization C#, duplicate nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization

This is my class structure

```
 [Serializable]
public class OrderXML
{
    [XmlArray("GROUPLIST")]
    public Group[] GroupList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "GROUP")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "SELLER", Type = typeof(Seller))]
    public Seller[] Sellers { get; set; }
}
```

The XML it is generating is

```
<GROUPLIST>
  <Group>
    <GROUP>
      <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
        ...
      </SELLER>
      <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
        ...
      </SELLER>
    </GROUP>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <GROUP>
      <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
        ...
      </SELLER>
      <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
       ...
      </SELLER>
    </GROUP>
  </Group>
</GROUPLIST>
```

The XML has duplicate **GROUP** and **Group** Tag, I am trying to remove that, I have checked the others answers mentioned in StackOverflow but they are not working in my case. Kindly help.

I am using XMLSerialization of C#

The answer by HimBromBeere is generating the XML

```
<GROUPLIST>
      <Group>
        <Sellers>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
            ...
          </SELLER>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
            ...
          </SELLER>
        </Sellers>
      </Group>
      <Group>
        <Sellers>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
            ...
          </SELLER>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
            ...
          </SELLER>
        </Sellers>
      </Group>
    </GROUPLIST>
```

I don't want the `<Sellers>` tag there

Comment: yes, i just want there to be one GROUP tag there, not the Group one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers by @Lesmian and @HimBromBree, I got rid of the GROUP duplicate tag, then to add the GROUPLIST tag I added another class in the middle. Thanks all

```
public class OrderXML
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GROUPLIST")]
        public GroupList GroupList { get; set; }
    }
    public class GroupList
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GROUP", Type = typeof(Group))]
        public Group[] Groups { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the `[XmlArray(ElementName = "GROUP")]` and `XmlArrayItem` from your member-definition of `public Seller[] Sellers { get; set; }` and add the `XmlElement`-attribute instead to the definition of the arrays:

```
public class OrderXML
{
    [XmlElement("GROUP")]
    public Group[] GroupList { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SELLER", Type = typeof(Seller))]
    public Seller[] Sellers { get; set; }
}
```

You can also add this attribute to your `OrderedXML`-class-member `Groups` instzead of the existing `XmlArrayItem`.
This will flatten the hierarchy in this way that the array comes immediately within the `<Group>`-tag.

Comment: just about to suggest that... Good answer.

Comment: `<GROUPLIST>
      <Group>
        <Sellers>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
            ..
          </SELLER>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
            ..
          </SELLER>
        </Sellers>
      </Group>
      <Group>
        <Sellers>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="1">
            ..
          </SELLER>
          <SELLER SELLERREF="2">
            ..
          </SELLER>
        </Sellers>
      </Group>
    </GROUPLIST>`


It is adding the **Sellers** in place of that, i just want the GroupLIST GROUP and SEller

Comment: HimBromBeere it is changing the GROUP tag to SELLERS, i want this tag to be removed completely, any suggestion

Comment: @UmairManzoor Edited

Comment: @HimBromBerre that did help but i had to add another class in between, thanks. Posted the working structure below

Comment: You won´t need an intermediate class, just change the `XmlElement` from `GroupList` within `OrderXML` to `XmlArrayItem` and you get both a `GroupList`- and a `Group`-tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think in order to do it you will need to specify xmlelement attribute instead of xmlarray in the Group class:

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderXML
{
    [XmlArray("GROUPLIST")]
    public Group[] GroupList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    [XmlElement("SELLER", Type = typeof(Seller))]
    public Seller[] Sellers { get; set; }
}
```

This should remove additional Group tag. Here you can find detaild info about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/12/customizing-the-xml-for-collections-with-xmlserializer-and-datacontractserializer.aspx.

Comment: Your answer added 2 <GROUPLIST> for each of the <GROUP>, didn't work

Comment: @UmairManzoor Hi, try my updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: that did help but i had to add another class in between, thanks. Posted the working structure below

Comment: @UmairManzoor are you sure that you need another class in-between? Notice that in the OrderXML class I used XmlArray attribute? Did you try it like that?

Comment: yes i did try the XMLArray way, but is did not work. So i had to add that extra class